# In kubernetes services, not able to use ports 6000 and 8081

Tags: kubernetes, port

I have a Kubernetes service (a Python Flask application) exposed publicly on port 6000 using the LoadBalancer type.

When I am using kubectl to send the YAML file to Kubernetes by running the following command:
**kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml**
I got the status of the service as running.

When I am navigating to http://localhost:6000, I am not able to see the “Hello from Python!”

I tried using port 8081, and that is also not working. But when I am using port 8088, it's working.

deployment.yaml file which I am using:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-python-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-python
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 6000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-python
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-python
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-python
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-python
        image: hello-python:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

I am using the following example:
[Kubernetes Using Python](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/23/get-started-with-kubernetes-using-python/)

Why some ports like 6000 or 8081 are not working and why some ports like 8088 or 9000 are working?

Comment: what kind of k8s cluster is this? Are these ports possibly already in use by something else?

Comment: Check with `netstat` for those ports, they might be already in use like PatrickW said.

Comment: No, these ports are not being used.

Comment: local clusters for testing Kubernetes

Comment: @MonikaKumari Can you be more specific on the local cluster. Are you using minikube, k3s, docker desktop etc? Not all k8s deployment methods support exposing a load balancer at localhost.

Comment: I am using docker desktop.